# Objective-c interfaces and implementations

Tags: objective-c

Is interface to an implementation is just like a function declaration (in a header file) to a function definition?
What if I didn't list in the interface all methods that are already implemented? What about instance variables as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes interface and implementation could be considered analogous to header and definition.

If you don't list some of the implemented methods, you won't be able to used them from other classes. Also if they are not defined in the `@interface` section, the compiler will complain if you try to use a function that has been implemented after the call

```
@implementation

- (void) functionA
{
     [self functionB]; // error, because 'so far' functionB has not been defined
}

- (void) functionB
{
}
```

EDIT: See Martin's comment below. END EDIT

If you don't define instance variables, and you use them you'll get errors. Any variable that you use MUST be defined, either locally or in the class.

Comment: What do you mean by an instance variable defined locally?

Comment: The current compiler version does *not* require forward declarations of methods within the implementation file.

Comment: @Naughty.Coder No, I meant a variable must defined either locally to the function or execution block (meaning it is not an instance variable) or as an instance variable in the class.

Comment: @MartinR Do you know from what compiler version are forward declarations not required?

Comment: @Merlevede: for at least 2 years Xcode's underlaying llvm does not need to have the "private" methods declared. implementation is just enough.

Comment: @Merlevede: if you use properties, you also don't need to declare the ivars anymore.

Comment: @vikingosegundo However, you still have to have a forward declaration for C functions if you want to use them earlier in the file than where they're defined

Comment: According to http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/314742-when-did-forward-method-references-become-legal.html, that feature came with Xcode 4.3.

Comment: also mentioned in wwdc 2012 video [«Modern Objective-C»](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#405-video) ~3:00 - ~6:00 & ~9:50 - ~12:00

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions:
Is interface to an implementation is just like a function declaration (in a header file) to a function definition?

YES

What if I didn't list in the interface all methods that are already implemented? What about instance variables as well?

These methods will be taken as private methods and variables which will be accessible in that particular class.

variables declared in your interface, as in 1., are visible in other classes that instantiate objects of MyClass. The variable declared in 2. will only be visible inside of MyClass. Here is something you should read: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/11/interface-and-implementation.html

I guess all these will help you in understanding these things in deeper.

Comment: There is no way to declare private methods in Objective-C. The methods will be accessible via `[object performSelector:@selector(methodName:)];` from any class knowing about object.